# Difference between a[..., n] & a[ : , n] indexing in numpy

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray, numpy-slicing

What is the difference between using `a[..., x]` & `a[:, x]` in `numpy` where `a` is any arbitrary array and `x` is an arbitrary number ?

Comment: Check out: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html

Comment: One selects on the last axis, the other on the 2nd.  '...' `ellipsis` should be documented someplace.